# Is there a utility that allows to open a terminal window with a shortcut?

Tags: snow-leopard, terminal

I often use the Terminal application, especially to commit code to a Git repository, and I don't want to have the window always open. Is there a utility that allows to open a terminal window using a shortcut?

Comment: are you asking if there is a utility that opens a terminal window and then closes it after your done? cause technically "Terminal" does what your asking

Comment: @luca590 I am asking for an application that opens a terminal window with a shortcut; I can reset my Mac, but I want to still be able to open a terminal window with a shortcut.

Comment: you can copy terminal and paste it to your desktop or where ever you feel necessary if that is sufficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm/) may be exactly what you are after: it's like a file location aware terminal that pops in and out of view. So you can activate it while you've got a file selected in terminal (or XCode, or whatever) and take an action on the file (like commit a change) and then it gets out your way.

It's free and also available on the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com) (see also the [Google project page](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/)). You can bind a key combination as a way to show/hide the terminal. In a way, you achieve the same thing as the before mentioned Visor; yet, iTerm2 offers more functionality than Terminal.app.

Combine this with alfred/quicksilver and iTerm2 profiles for more hotkey awesomeness.

Answer (score 3):

Visor does that: http://visor.binaryage.com/

In case you just want a command line, use: http://decimus.net/DTerm/

Answer (score 3):

Use [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/)! You can setup hot-keys for launching apps. Plus it does a bunch of other neat things :)

Answer (score 1):

[Alfred](http://alfredapp.com) is a wonderful Quicksilver-like app that can do this, providing that you purchase the [PowerPack](http://www.alfredapp.com/powerpack/).  I use this quite frequently; I just bring up the window and type `> cd ~/Developer` and then hit <kbd>return</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I like [apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/), it ain't free.. but it's superfast (unlike visor eg)!
It works for any app, plus you get a *peek* option, alowing you to peek into the shortcutted app.

Answer (score 0):

I just press Apple and space to bring up spotlight

Followed by typing 'te' which finds terminal and then hit return.